# Why is tmux starting slower and slower over time?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh, tmux

On my Ubuntu server I run tmux. When I login on the server itself I get tmux, when I login with SSH I get tmux too.
Right after a reboot logging in on the server starts tmux within seconds and when logging in with SSH it starts within seconds too.
After a few weeks and login attempts both locally and remote, logging in with SSH still starts tmux within seconds while with logging in locally on the server tmux starts slower and slower. I've experienced delays of over 20 minutes before tmux appears.
 I don't know what's wrong but somehow it seems to be server related. How can I solve this? There are no errormessages regarding tmux.

Comment: Are you logging or auditing everything? Does your terminal have the history set to infinite?

Comment: I'm logging things that the server is logging by default so I didn't add additional things to log. The history is set to a value substantially larger than the default but it isn't set to infinite.

Comment: Running a `strace` and `valgrind` on tmux might provide additional insight. 

Some basic performance stats like `vmstat` and friends would help as well.

Reproducing with a standard / clean config and the latest stable / latest snapshot version respectively would also help narrow it down. Of course - you may need to speed up the process (ex: automate a bunch of attach / detach operations and see if there's a change in the footprint).

Comment: Is it just tmux that loads/runs slowly?  Also, when you say "when I login on the server itself I get tmux, when I login with SSH I get tmux too", what do you mean?  Do you have something that's launching tmux automatically in your bashrc (attaching sessions recursively)? What else is running?  Is your server a VM? Do you have sar running - it can tell you how much memory is in use, etc.

Comment: @Liczyrzepa Tmux starts automatically when I log in to the server whether it is over SSH or physically on the server itself. It is a real server and not a VM. The server is running multiple other processen like a webserver. Limited available memory might be an issue.

Comment: I'm not aware of default configuration that spawns tmux upon login.  You should check your ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc scripts (system wide is in /etc/bashrc and /etc/profile).  Also, what does `tmux list-sessions` show?

Comment: @Liczyrzepa I've made it to start automatically. The problem is the increasing starting time not the fact that it starts.

Comment: So _assuming_ you're not recursively starting tmux sessions (we don't know because you haven't shared exactly how you're starting tmux), what does `ps auxww` show when tmux starts slowly for you?  Also you only partially answered Aaron's question (how big is your history? we don't know).  Some basic troubleshooting information would help here.  Criveti suggested `vmstat` - please share this information - it will help everyone find an answer to your question.

Comment: For memory issues see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535630/tmux-using-1g-ram-even-after-clearing-all-scrollback-history

Comment: @Liczyrzepa recursively starting tmux in the bashrc or bash_profile (basically forcing tmux to start against all warnings) is an infinite loop. Personal experience...

Comment: @Atav32 No, it's not.You can attach and detach sessions as you see fit and that is what I'm doing.

Comment: @wie5Ooma doesn't sound like what you're doing is recursive

Comment: I have the same problem when attaching to an existing tmux session on my server with `tmux a` it takes several minutes if the session is running for a few weeks already. (I suspect, that if there is a long history in one of the screens inside the session, this makes it a really slow start. When i exit all screens and start a new session, everything runs fast again. related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767832/tmux-scrolling-itself-is-fast-but-after-some-weeks-of-running-the-tmux-session

Answer (score 3):

For me, that was a problem with the following line in my `.zprofile`:

```
echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /home/gbajson/.zprofile
```

After a few weeks I had over 700 following lines in `.zprofile`, so the starts were slower and slower.

```
gbajson@misio:~$ grep -c "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv" .zprofile
715
```

Comment: I had a line in /etc/profile.d/  that ended up filling my .bashrc with over 26000 lines! Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you are detaching or doing a hard disconnect (something like closing the terminal emulator) from the session when you are finished and running simply `tmux` every time you connect, then you are creating a new session every time.  Make sure you use something like `tmux a || tmux` when you login/connect.