# tmux scrolling itself is fast, but after some weeks of running the tmux session, the start is slow

Tags: tmux, xen

when i start scrolling back in tmux with CTRL+b+PgUp it first starts directly, but over time it starts really slow - some minutes untill the backscroll starts. When it is started, everything is milliseconds fast again.

I have set the history to 300000 lines in `.tmux.conf`

```
set-option -g history-limit
```

But I thought this should be no problem for a modern fast online-server. Or could this be related to a long history, that has to be loaded, before the backscrolling can start?

Is there another file to define the history length?
maybe my my `.bashrc`:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
HISTFILESIZE=999999999
HISTSIZE=999999999
```

Ore could this be related to slow Hard-disks in my server?

The server is running on Xen with a HDD-Raid and an SSD-Raid. The Dom0 where I run the tmux session in is on the HDD but all other VMS are on SSD.

*Related but different*: [Why is tmux starting slower and slower over time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247234/why-is-tmux-starting-slower-and-slower-over-time)
There the problem is during the start of the session, which is solveable by closing the session and starting a new one. But it might be the same reason as here

Comment: Huge scollback buffers are slow to load, and make your memory footprint bigger. I have a better way, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals/80882#80882